# Waze and iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios

I love using the Waze App with my iPhone 5, except for one very annoying problem:   while driving and Waze engaged, I listen to music on the radio, but I keep getting interruptions in the radio where the radio screen shows my phone name and phone number indicating I am calling myself.

It happens often and only when  I have Waze activated.  I don't know if it is a switch on the phone or something with Waze.    I would like it to stop because it's  very distracting and annoying.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Waze since, by your own admission, the problem only occurs while using Waze?  Also, what version of iOS?

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to Waze Settings > Sound & Voice > Sound Output, you can set how you want Waze to output sound. If you set it to "Play on phone speaker", then any alerts that come from Waze wont use your car's Bluetooth audio.

As for all the settings, Device default *generally* treats Waze audio like Bluetooth music audio, where play as "Bluetooth phone call" uses your car's Bluetooth phone call function. Playing from phone speaker bypasses the car's Bluetooth function entirely, preventing it from playing Waze audio through your car's speakers.